# t-SQL USE keyword issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say, I just created a database, then created a login and and now I need to assign a user to it. So I do:

```
CREATE DATABASE [testdb2] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
CREATE LOGIN testusr1 WITH PASSWORD = 'mystrongpassword';
USE [testdb2];
CREATE USER testusr1 FOR LOGIN testusr1;
```

But the `USE` line returns this error:

> Database 'testdb2' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered
>   correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) commands:

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL
>   Server utilities.

**E.g.,**

```
CREATE DATABASE [testdb2] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
GO
CREATE LOGIN testusr1 WITH PASSWORD = 'mystrongpassword';
GO
USE [testdb2];
GO
CREATE USER testusr1 FOR LOGIN testusr1;
```

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor. SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should
>   send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of
>   SQL Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all
>   statements entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc
>   session or script if this is the first GO. A Transact-SQL statement
>   cannot occupy the same line as a GO command. However, the line can
>   contain comments. Users must follow the rules for batches. For
>   example, any execution of a stored procedure after the first statement
>   in a batch must include the EXECUTE keyword. The scope of local
>   (user-defined) variables is limited to a batch, and cannot be
>   referenced after a GO command.

Comment: +1 but just to be pedantic and prevent ambiguity, `GO` isn't a statement per se (and isn't really part of T-SQL), it's just a batch separator for certain client tools like Management Studio.

Comment: Hmm. My reasoning behind dropping `GO` was to execute all those statements in "one batch". Is it contradicting the `USE` statement then?

Comment: If you do them in one batch, then the parser cannot find the testdb2 object because it does not exist yet, so throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GO after your CREATE DATABASE statement, and also after your CREATE LOGIN statement. 
GO is used as a batch separator. You can changed this if you want to use something else as a batch separator instead of GO. Go to Tools -> Options -> Query Execution, and see the Batch Separator section. 
GO can also be used with an int parameter for example:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT 1, 2, 3
GO 10
```

Which will insert the values into #tmp 10 times.